# How to apply styles to the HTML Table in the email?

Tags: html, css, .net

I am working on a windows service application that sends a N number of Rows of a Database Table as a HTML table through (SMTP)email ,I am receiving the mail without the columns and rows,i just received the text from the table .

This the Code i used to convert the DB table to HTML table:

```
 public StringBuilder CreateHtmlTable(DataTable dt)
{

    string tab = "\t";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("<html>");
    sb.AppendLine(tab + "<body>");
    sb.AppendLine("<p>This is The test mail</p>");
    sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table>");


    sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>", dc.ColumnName);
    }

    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");


    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
            sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
        }

        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }

    sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "</table>");
    sb.AppendLine(tab + "</body>");
    sb.AppendLine("</html>");
    return sb;
}
```

How to achieve this ?please

Comment: @Seting Solita mattum paya poriyaa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append like this only na,

```
sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table style=\"color:green;\">");
```

Are you not getting the expected output if you do like above ? Try and know......